# Let $G$ be a group with $|a_i|=n_i$ for all $1\le i \le m$. Show that $|x|=n_1n_2\ldots n_m$ where $x$ defined as follows

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

Let $(G,*)$ be a group. Let $a_i \in G, |a_i|=n_i, 1 \le i \le m$. Suppose $\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1$ and $a_ia_j=a_ja_i$, for all $i$ and $j$. Let $x=a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_m$. Show that
$|x| = n_1n_2\ldots n_m$.

Does it could be proved using induction on $m$? If yes, what about the base case? If I let $P(m)$ be the statement, then the base case is: $P(1)$ true
since $|x| = |a_1| = n_1$, isn't it?

Comment: You do not need induction if you do not want.  Consider that for $x \in G$ with finite order $i$ that if $x^k = e$ then $(x^i)^j = e^j = e$ for some $j,k$.  Then with $x=a_1 a_2 ... a_m $ take $x^k$ and use the commutativity to get $x^k = a_1^k a_2^k ... a_m^k$ and consider what it would mean if $gcd(n_1...n_m,k) \ne n_1...n_m$.

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Could you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Here I got so far. Please give me a correction if I make some mistakes.

Let $a_i \in G, |a_i| = n_i$ where $1\le i \le m$. Given that $\gcd(n_i,n_j) = 1$ and
$a_ia_j = a_ja_i$ for all $i$ and $j$.
Let $e_G$ be the identity element in $G$.

Let $P(m)$ be the statement:

The order of $a_1a_2\ldots a_m$ is $n_1n_2\cdots n_m$.

**Base Case:**
Consider $P(2)$. That is, the order of
$a_1a_2$ is $n_1n_2$. We'll show it now.
Note that $|a_1| = n_1$ and $|a_2|=n_2$.
Let $|a_1a_2| = s$.

To show that $s=n_1n_2$:

- $s \mid n_1n_2$:
  Notice that
  \begin{align*}
  (a_1a_2)^{n_1n_2} &= \overset{n_1n_2}{\overbrace{abab \ldots ab}} \\
  &= \overset{n_1n_2}{\overbrace{a_1a_1\ldots a_1}}
  \overset{n_1n_2}{\overbrace{a_2a_2\ldots a_2}} \\
  &= a_1^{n_1n_2}a_2^{n_1n_2} \\
  &= (a_1^{n_1})^{n_2}((a_2)^{n_2})^{n_1} \\
  &= (e_G)(e_G) \\
  &= e_G
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $s \mid n_1n_2$, as desired.
- $n_1n_2 \mid s$:
  Consider that
  \begin{align*}
  e_G = (a_1a_2)^s &= (a_1a_2)^{sn_1} \\
  &= a_1^{sn_1}a_2^{sn_1} \\ 
  &= (a_1^{n_1})^sa_2^{sn_1} \\
  &= (e_G)a_2^{sn_1} \\
  &= a_2^{sn_1}.
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $n_2 \mid sn_1$. Since
  $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$, then we must have
  $n_2 \mid s$. Similarly, consider
  \begin{align*}
  e_G = (a_1a_2)^s &= (a_1a_2)^{sn_2} \\
  &= a_1^{sn_2}a_2^{sn_2} \\ 
  &= a_1^{sn_2}(a_2^{n_2})^s \\
  &= a_1^{sn_2}(e_G) \\
  &= a_1^{sn_2}.
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $n_1 \mid sn_2$. Since
  $\gcd(n_1,n_2) = 1$, then we must have
  $n_1 \mid s$.
  Thus, we have $n_1n_2 \mid s$, as desired.

Hence, $s = n_1n_2. \Box$.

Thus, the order of $a_1a_2$ is $n_1n_2$
i.e. $P(2)$ is true.

**Inductive Step:**
Let $x=a_1a_2\ldots a_k$ and $n=n_1n_2\cdots n_k$.
Assume that $P(k)$ is true. That is, the order of $x$ is $n$.

To show $P(k+1)$ is also true (that is, the order of $xa_{k+1}$ is $nn_{k+1}$.):
Notice that
\begin{align*}
a_1a_2\ldots a_{k+1} &= a_1a_2\ldots a_ka_{k+1} \\
&= (a_1a_2\ldots a_k)a_{k+1} \\
&= xa_{k+1}.
\end{align*}
Now, we apply the same method as in the base case above. Here we go:

Let $|xa_{k+1}| = t$. To show that
$t = nn_{k+1}$:

- $t \mid nn_{k+1}$:
  Consider that
  \begin{align*}
  (xa_{k+1})^{nn_{k+1}} &=
  \overset{nn_{k+1}}{\overbrace{xa_{k+1}xa_{k+1}\ldots xa_{k+1}}} \\
  &= \overset{nn_{k+1}}{\overbrace{xx\ldots x}}\overset{nn_{k+1}}{\overbrace{a_{k+1}a_{k+1}\ldots a_{k+1}}} \\
  &= (x^n)^{n_{k+1}}(a_{k+1}^{n_{k+1}})^n
  \\
  &= (e_G)(e_G) \\
  &= e_G.
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $t \mid nn_{k+1}$, as desired.
- $nn_{k+1} \mid t$:
  Consider that
  \begin{align*}
  e_G = (xa_{k+1})^t &= (xa_{k+1})^{tn} \\
  &= x^{tn}a_{k+1}^{tn} \\
  &= (x^n)^ta_{k+1}^{tn} \\
  &= (e_G)a_{k+1}^{tn} \\
  &= a_{k+1}^{tn}.
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $n_{k+1} \mid tn$.
  But, since $\gcd(n,n_{k+1}) = 1$, then we must have $n_{k+1} \mid t$.
  Similarly, consider that
  \begin{align*}
  e_G = (xa_{k+1})^t &= (xa_{k+1})^{tn_{k+1}} \\
  &= x^{tn_{k+1}}a_{k+1}^{tn_{k+1}} \\
  &= x^{tn_{k+1}}a_{k+1}^{tn_{k+1}} \\
  &= x^{tn_{k+1}}(a_{k+1}^{n_{k+1}})^t \\
  &= x^{tn_{k+1}}(e_G) \\
  &= x^{tn_{k+1}}.
  \end{align*}
  Hence, $n \mid tn_{k+1}$. Since
  $\gcd(n,n_{k+1}) = 1$, then we must have
  $n \mid t$.
  Thus, we have $nn_{k+1} \mid t$, as desired.

Hence, $nn_{k+1} = t. \Box$.

Thus, the order of $xa_{k+1}$ is
$nn_{k+1}$ i.e. $P(k+1)$ holds.

Therefore, the order of $a_1a_2\ldots a_m$ is $n_1n_2\cdots n_m$ and hence proved. $\Box$

Answer (score -1):

You need the base case to be $P(2)$ because your inductive step will look something like:

...Assuming P(n), consider $$x_1\cdot ... \cdot x_n\cdot x_{n+1} = (x_1\cdot ... \cdot x_n )\cdot x_{n+1} $$
Applying $P(2)$, this has order $|x_1\cdot ... \cdot x_n|| x_{n+1}|$...

Comment: Could you check my answer below?